# How can I mock instance in ASP.NET Core unit test using Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Writing unit test with nunit in asp.net core service, I try to write controller unit test.

```cs
[ApiController]
public class ConvertController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<ConvertController> _logger;
    private readonly Factory.IWorkbookFactory _workbookFactory;

    public ConvertController(ILogger<ConvertController> logger, Factory.IWorkbookFactory workbookFactory)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _workbookFactory = workbookFactory;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/v1/[controller]/pdf")]
    public ConvertResponse Post(ConvertRequest req)
    {
        ConvertResponse res = new ConvertResponse();
        res.OutputData = new Converter(_workbookFactory.newInstance()).ExcelToPDF(req.InputData);

        return res;
    }
}
```

In this case, can I mock whole Converter instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@naruke, in order to mock `Converter' type it need to be injected so the code shall have to be modified as below.

Firstly, implement the `Converter`like this.

Create interface IConverter.

```
public interface IConverter
{
 /*OutPut */ ExcelToPDF(/* input*/);
}
```

then implement

```
class Converter:IConverter
{
 ....
}
```

Now no need to inject `IWorkbookFactory`

```
[ApiController]
public class ConvertController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<ConvertController> _logger;
    //private readonly Factory.IWorkbookFactory _workbookFactory;
    private readonly IConverter _converter;
    public ConvertController(ILogger<ConvertController> logger,IConverter converter // Factory.IWorkbookFactory workbookFactory)
    {
    _logger = logger;
    //_workbookFactory = workbookFactory;
    _converter=converter;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/v1/[controller]/pdf")]
    public ConvertResponse Post(ConvertRequest req)
    {
        ConvertResponse res = new ConvertResponse();
        res.OutputData = _converter.ExcelToPDF(req.InputData);

        return res;
    }
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your information. But, I need `IWorkbookFactory` to use `ExcelToPDF()` unit test in `Converter`

Comment: I am not sure about what you mean by `I need IWorkbookFactory to use ExcelToPDF()` . `ExcelToPDF()` is a method within the `Converter` class. Please explain your question in more detail and the objective.